# Initialise class and having problems with undefined offset

Tags: php, oop, offset

Im recently moving across from procedural to oop with my php, im studying from a book and as well as doing the exercises and projects in the book i am also giving myself a real life project to do for my own website.

I want to implement an sms feature to my website and while researching the project came across this small class library that connects to the API of the company i will be using, the library is on github and seems to be unsupported and my emails to the developer are bouncing back.

This is the [library](https://github.com/nicksantamaria/smsbroadcastau_php) and this is the code i use to initialise it:

```
require_once('classes/class.smsquick.php');

$username = "someuser";
$password = "somepass";

$api = new SmsQuick($username, $password);

//uncommenting the line below returns undefined_index @ line 312 and 282
//$available_credits = $api->checkBalance(); 

//var_dump($api); //used for checking
```

These are the errors i am receiving:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\websites\ooptuts\public\classes\class.smsquick.php on line 312
>
> Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\websites\ooptuts\public\classes\class.smsquick.php on line 282

lines 312 and 282 are pointed out in the next two methods, the final two methods are required so i have shown those also:

```
public function checkBalance() {
    $vars = array(
        'username' => $this->api_username,
        'password' => $this->api_password,
        'action' => 'balance',
    );

    $retval = $this->executeApiRequest($vars);
    list(, $response) = array_values(reset($retval)); // line 282

    return (int) $response;
}

/**
 * Helper method to execute an API request.
 *
 * @param array $vars
 *   Data to POST to SMS gateway API endpoint.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Response from SMS gateway.
 */
public function executeApiRequest($vars) {
    // Basic validation on the authentication details
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'username':
            case 'password':
                if (empty($value)) {
                    throw new Exception('API username or password not specified.');
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    $data = $this->preparePostData($vars);
    $retval = $this->executePostRequest($data);

    list($status, $response) = explode(':', $retval); // line 312
    if ($status == 'ERROR') {
        throw new Exception(strtr('There was an error with this request: !error.', array('!error' => $response)));
    }

    $data = array();
    $lines = explode("\n", $retval);
    foreach (array_filter($lines) as $i => $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        $data[$i] = explode(':', $line);
    }

    return $data;
}

protected function preparePostData($data) {
    $post_data = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        switch ($key) {
            case 'to':
                // Support multiple phone numbers.
                $value = implode(',', array_unique($value));
                break;
        }
        $post_data[] = $key . '=' . rawurlencode($value);
    }

    return implode('&', $post_data);
}

protected function executePostRequest($data) {
    $ch = curl_init($this->api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $retval = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retval;
}
```

Are the problems caused by how i am initialising the class or something that i am overlooking?.. i seem to have spent two days running around in circles with google etc and not making much progress and would appreciate some advice from others.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because reset() returns a Boolean.  Move the reset() call to its own line:

```
reset($retval);
list(, $response) = array_values($retval); // line 282
```

I should say it returns the first value, however in your case its returning FALSE

From the [PHP Manual: reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

Also, its possible that on line 312 the array you are passing in is empty.  Try printing out the value of the array to be sure.  Perhaps your CURL call is not returning what you expect.

Comment: You certainly were on the right track, I did not have to change the reset line, the problem was with the ssl certificate, i reinstalled Wamp last week and stupidly forgot to include cacert.pem to my Wamp folder which was obviously returning bad data via curl response. Many thanks. Marked as answered.

Comment: Glad I could help.  To be honest, I read the problem in reverse.  I should have made the suggestion that the CURL call be looked at first, but the way I read the issue I had it backward.  Still I'd keep the reset call on its own line in case the $retval value does end up being empty.  You can put some error checking there as well if necessary